# Trouble having port mapping two modules in one

Tags: vhdl

This is a control unit for my 16 bit MIPS, I am trying to connect the alucontrol to the alu unit opcode but since it was an output and alu unit op a input i used a signal opsignal, the code gives no syntax error but shows this warning i have mentioned below.

I am a newbie and I don't know how to connect my aluunit to control unit even if I am actually connecting it. 
Also if I am not using funct, A and B so it will run with the same logic, right? I mentioned these inputs and outputs in my port map but it showed error as they were open ports. Using 'open' did not fix the problem so I just removed them, does it affect my code? There are so many warnings. I just don't know how to resolve them

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity controlunit is 
  Port ( opcode : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2 downto 0);
         --zero : in  STD_LOGIC;
         w_en : out  STD_LOGIC;
         regdst : out  STD_LOGIC;
         alusrc : out  STD_LOGIC;
         --branch : out  STD_LOGIC;
         memwrite : out  STD_LOGIC;
         memtoreg : out  STD_LOGIC;
         alucontrol : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0);
         pcsrc : out  STD_LOGIC);
end controlunit;

architecture Behavioral of controlunit is

  component maindecoder is
    Port ( opcode : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2 downto 0);
           w_en : out  STD_LOGIC;
           regdst : out  STD_LOGIC;
           alusrc : out  STD_LOGIC;
           branch : out  STD_LOGIC;
           memwrite : out  STD_LOGIC;
           memtoreg : out  STD_LOGIC
           --aluop : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0)
         );
  end component;

  component alu is
    Port ( --clk: in STD_LOGIC;
           --A : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0);
           --B : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0);
           --funct: in STD_LOGIC;
           op: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0);
           zero  : out std_logic;
           Result : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0));    
  end component;

  --signal alusig: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0);
  signal opsignal: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0);
  signal branch: STD_LOGIC;
  signal zero: STD_logic;

begin

  -- instantiate maindecoder
  decoder: maindecoder port map (opcode => opcode, w_en => w_en,
           regdst => regdst, alusrc => alusrc, branch => branch, memwrite => memwrite, memtoreg => memtoreg);

  aluunit: alu port map (op => opsignal, zero => zero);

  alucontrol <= opsignal;

  pcsrc <= branch and zero;

end Behavioral;


WARNING:Xst:753 - "E:/Xilinx Projects/controlunit/controlunit.vhd" line 46: Unconnected output port 'aluop' of component 'maindecoder'.
WARNING:Xst:753 - "E:/Xilinx Projects/controlunit/controlunit.vhd" line 49: Unconnected output port 'Result' of component 'alu'.
WARNING:Xst:752 - "E:/Xilinx Projects/controlunit/controlunit.vhd" line 49: Unconnected input port 'clk' of component 'alu' is tied to default value.
WARNING:Xst:752 - "E:/Xilinx Projects/controlunit/controlunit.vhd" line 49: Unconnected input port 'A' of component 'alu' is tied to default value.
WARNING:Xst:752 - "E:/Xilinx Projects/controlunit/controlunit.vhd" line 49: Unconnected input port 'B' of component 'alu' is tied to default value. 
WARNING:Xst:752 - "E:/Xilinx Projects/controlunit/controlunit.vhd" line 49: Unconnected input port 'funct' of component 'alu' is tied to default value.
WARNING:Xst:653 - Signal <opsignal> is used but never assigned. This sourceless signal will be automatically connected to value 00.
WARNING:Xst:1290 - Hierarchical block <aluunit> is unconnected in block <controlunit>. It will be removed from the design.
```

Code for alu:

```
   library IEEE;
   use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
   use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;
   use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;

  entity alu is 
  Port ( clk: in STD_LOGIC;
          A : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0);
       B : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0);
          funct: in STD_LOGIC;
          op: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0);
          zero  : out std_logic;
       Result : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0));

  end alu;

  architecture Behavioral of alu is
begin
 process (clk, op, funct, A, B)
 begin
  if (clk'event and clk = '1') then
    case op is
        when "00" => Result <= A+B;
        when "01" => Result <= A-B;
        when "10" => case funct is 
                        when '0' => Result <= A+B;
                        when '1' => Result <= A-B;
                        when others => null;
                        end case;
        when others => null;
    end case;
    end if;
end process;
    process (A,B) begin
        if (A = B) then
        zero <= '1';
        else zero <= '0';
        end if;
    end process;
   end;
```

Code for maindecoder

```
   ibrary IEEE;
   use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
   use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

   entity maindecoder is
   Port ( opcode : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2 downto 0);
       w_en : out  STD_LOGIC;
       regdst : out  STD_LOGIC;
       alusrc : out  STD_LOGIC;
       branch : out  STD_LOGIC;
       memwrite : out  STD_LOGIC;
       memtoreg : out  STD_LOGIC;
       aluop : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0));
  end maindecoder;

  architecture Behavioral of maindecoder is
  signal control: std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
  begin
    process (opcode)
begin
    case opcode is
        when "000" => control <= "11000010"; -- R-type
        when "001" => control <= "10100100"; --lw
        when "010" => control <= "00101000"; --sw
        when "011" => control <= "00010001";--beq
        when others => control<= "--------";        --illegal opcode
    end case;
end process;

w_en    <= control(7);
regdst  <= control(6);
alusrc  <= control(5);
branch  <= control(4);
memwrite <= control(3);
memtoreg <= control(2);
aluop       <= control(1 downto 0);

   end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Most of these messages are telling you you're leaving ports unconnected. You also may need to make sure your port list for the entities `maindecoder` and `alu` are consistent with the component declarations here.

Comment: Yeah I left them on purpose because I dont need them here. When I included them I got an error something like port A needs a default value or something. So I removed it. Do you know how this can be resolved? should i post my codes for alu and decoder?

Comment: At least post the entity definitions. One of the warnings is clear from what you posted here already, though - `Result` is a port on `alu`, but you don't have it mapped (this may be what you wanted, but that's why you're getting the warning, anyway).

Comment: okay i will post the whole thing.

Comment: @fru1tbat there you go man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> WARNING:Xst:753 - "E:/Xilinx Projects/controlunit/controlunit.vhd" line 46: Unconnected output port 'aluop' of component 'maindecoder'.

The problem here is exactly what it says (you left an output unconnected, which isn't an error), but it's related to a more critical error further on:

> WARNING:Xst:653 - Signal <opsignal> is used but never assigned. This sourceless signal will be automatically connected to value 00.

You probably meant to map `opsignal` to the `aluop` output on `maindecoder`.

> WARNING:Xst:753 - "E:/Xilinx Projects/controlunit/controlunit.vhd" line 49: Unconnected output port 'Result' of component 'alu'.

Again, exactly what it says. Are you sure you don't want to connect `Result`?

The rest of the errors indicate you have some other fairly serious problems, namely, you've left a bunch of inputs unconnected - you've commented out a bunch of ports on your component declaration for `alu` and not mapped them. Why? Note that these ports are fairly critical to the operation of `alu` - without at least some of them, it won't actually do anything.

**(edit)**

Re: your comment "I used a signal because I cannot map an output to an input.":

`op` is an input to `alu` because `alu` "reads" it, in a manner of speaking. `alu` does not generate that value or drive that port - it has to come from somewhere else, possibly outside the code you've posted here. Therefore, trying to obtain its value from `alu` is meaningless. You need to determine what the *source* of that control is. If it's `maindecoder`, then you can compose it from that component's outputs, but I'm not sure if that's what you need.

Comment: I will just explain what I was trying to do here, the last two bits of my control port decides which alu function I need to perforem, these bits should be mapped with the opcode of my alu. Basically I am designing a control unit, the alucontrol is the output of this control unit and it needs to be mapped with the last two bits of my control port. I used a signal because I cannot map an output to an input. I do need the whole functionality for this alu, would my code not work if i just map the op?

Comment: The `alu` code shows that `zero` is a function of `A` and `B`. `Result` is as well, and also depends on `clk` and (partially) `funct`. As you are instantiating `alu` inside `controlunit`, you will need to provide inputs that `alu` needs as inputs to `controlunit` as well.

Comment: As I read your comment again, I'm a little confused. `alucontrol` is your output - what do you mean it needs to be mapped with the last 2 bits of your "control port"? Which port are you referring to? Also, when you said you used a signal because "you can't map an output to an input" - I think you're misunderstanding how these signals flow. I will update my answer.

Comment: Yes you are right, i need to review my logic and code.